Google gemini generate_content is not working in python API using function calling function_response
I'm trying to make the same request that I did in CURL which works. But in Python is not working.
The gemini docs:
https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/function-calling?hl=pt-br#multi-turn-example-1
The curl request:
import requests

url = "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-pro:generateContent"
api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"  # Replace with your actual API key

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

data = {
    "contents": [
        {
            "role": "user",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "text": "Which theaters in Mountain View show Barbie movie?"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "role": "model",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "functionCall": {
                        "name": "find_theaters",
                        "args": {
                            "location": "Mountain View, CA",
                            "movie": "Barbie"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "role": "function",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "functionResponse": {
                        "name": "find_theaters",
                        "response": {
                            "name": "find_theaters",
                            "content": {
                                "movie": "Barbie",
                                "theaters": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "AMC Mountain View 16",
                                        "address": "2000 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA 94040"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Regal Edwards 14",
                                        "address": "245 Castro St, Mountain View, CA 94040"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "tools": [
        {
            "functionDeclarations": [
                {
                    "name": "find_movies",
                    "description": "find movie titles currently playing in theaters based on any description, genre, title words, etc.",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "OBJECT",
                        "properties": {
                            "location": {
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA or a zip code e.g. 95616"
                            },
                            "description": {
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "description": "Any kind of description including category or genre, title words, attributes, etc."
                            }
                        },
                        "required": ["description"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "find_theaters",
                    "description": "find theaters based on location and optionally movie title which is currently playing in theaters",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "OBJECT",
                        "properties": {
                            "location": {
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA or a zip code e.g. 95616"
                            },
                            "movie": {
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "description": "Any movie title"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": ["location"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "get_showtimes",
                    "description": "Find the start times for movies playing in a specific theater",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "OBJECT",
                        "properties": {
                            "location": {
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA or a zip code e.g. 95616"
                            },
                            "movie": {
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "description": "Any movie title"
                            },
                            "theater": {
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "description": "Name of the theater"
                            },
                            "date": {
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "description": "Date for requested showtime"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": ["location", "movie", "theater", "date"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, params={'key': api_key})

print(response.json())

Using vertex API:
messages = [
        {
            "role": "user",
            "parts": [{"text": "Which theaters in Mountain View show Barbie movie?"}],
        },
        {
            "role": "model",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "function_call": {
                        "name": "find_theaters",
                        "args": {"location": "Mountain View, CA", "movie": "Barbie"},
                    }
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "role": "function",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "function_response": {
                        "name": "find_theaters",
                        "response": {
                            "name": "find_theaters",
                            "content": {
                                "movie": "Barbie",
                                "theaters": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "AMC Mountain View 16",
                                        "address": "2000 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA 94040",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Regal Edwards 14",
                                        "address": "245 Castro St, Mountain View, CA 94040",
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        },
                    }
                }
            ],
        },
    ]

    # Define the tools
    tools = [
        {
            "function_declarations": [
                {
                    "name": "find_movies",
                    "description": "find movie titles currently playing in theaters based on any description, genre, title words, etc.",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "location": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA or a zip code e.g. 95616",
                            },
                            "description": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "Any kind of description including category or genre, title words, attributes, etc.",
                            },
                        },
                        "required": ["description"],
                    },
                },
                {
                    "name": "find_theaters",
                    "description": "find theaters based on location and optionally movie title which is currently playing in theaters",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "location": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA or a zip code e.g. 95616",
                            },
                            "movie": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "Any movie title",
                            },
                        },
                        "required": ["location"],
                    },
                },
                {
                    "name": "get_showtimes",
                    "description": "Find the start times for movies playing in a specific theater",
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "location": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA or a zip code e.g. 95616",
                            },
                            "movie": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "Any movie title",
                            },
                            "theater": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "Name of the theater",
                            },
                            "date": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "description": "Date for requested showtime",
                            },
                        },
                        "required": ["location", "movie", "theater", "date"],
                    },
                },
            ]
        }
    ]

    model = GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")

    model.generate_content(messages, tool_config=tool_config, tools=tools)

The error:
ValueError: Protocol message Struct has no "location" field.
Please note that I took it from Gemini documentation, but I could not find how it should work in python

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to convert your top script with google-generativeai.

In this case, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
import google.generativeai as genai
import google.ai.generativelanguage as glm

apiKey = "###" # Please set your API key.

genai.configure(api_key=apiKey)

tool = glm.Tool(
    function_declarations=[
        glm.FunctionDeclaration(
            name="find_movies",
            description="find movie titles currently playing in theaters based on any description, genre, title words, etc.",
            parameters=glm.Schema(
                type=glm.Type.OBJECT,
                properties={
                    "location": glm.Schema(
                        type=glm.Type.STRING,
                        description="The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA or a zip code e.g. 95616",
                    ),
                    "description": glm.Schema(
                        type=glm.Type.STRING,
                        description="Any kind of description including category or genre, title words, attributes, etc.",
                    ),
                },
                required=["description"],
            ),
        ),
        glm.FunctionDeclaration(
            name="find_theaters",
            description="find theaters based on location and optionally movie title which is currently playing in theaters",
            parameters=glm.Schema(
                type=glm.Type.OBJECT,
                properties={
                    "location": glm.Schema(
                        type=glm.Type.STRING,
                        description="The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA or a zip code e.g. 95616",
                    ),
                    "movie": glm.Schema(
                        type=glm.Type.STRING,
                        description="Any movie title",
                    ),
                },
                required=["location"],
            ),
        ),
        glm.FunctionDeclaration(
            name="get_showtimes",
            description="Find the start times for movies playing in a specific theater",
            parameters=glm.Schema(
                type=glm.Type.OBJECT,
                properties={
                    "location": glm.Schema(
                        type=glm.Type.STRING,
                        description="The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA or a zip code e.g. 95616",
                    ),
                    "movie": glm.Schema(
                        type=glm.Type.STRING,
                        description="Any movie title",
                    ),
                    "theater": glm.Schema(
                        type=glm.Type.STRING,
                        description="Name of the theater",
                    ),
                    "date": glm.Schema(
                        type=glm.Type.STRING,
                        description="Date for requested showtime",
                    ),
                },
                required=["location", "movie", "theater", "date"],
            ),
        ),
    ]
)
model = genai.GenerativeModel("gemini-pro", tools=[tool])
messages = [
    glm.Part(text="Which theaters in Mountain View show Barbie movie?"),
    glm.Part(
        function_call=glm.FunctionCall(
            name="find_theaters",
            args={"location": "Mountain View, CA", "movie": "Barbie"},
        )
    ),
    glm.Part(
        function_response=glm.FunctionResponse(
            name="find_theaters",
            response={
                "name": "find_theaters",
                "content": {
                    "movie": "Barbie",
                    "theaters": [
                        {
                            "name": "AMC Mountain View 16",
                            "address": "2000 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA 94040",
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Regal Edwards 14",
                            "address": "245 Castro St, Mountain View, CA 94040",
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        )
    ),
]
response = model.generate_content(messages)
print(response.text)

Testing:
When this script is run, the following result is obtained.
There are two theaters in Mountain View showing Barbie movie: AMC Mountain View 16 and Regal Edwards 14.

